# Optimizing techniques - advice needed for Asynchronous function

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

We have about four million zip files and each contains two images. These zip files are stored as BLOBs in an Oracle table. The requirement is to resize those images and insert them as BLOBs (but now JPEGs) in a different table.
Therefore, what I did was:
1. Retrieve each zip file and save it to the file system.
2. Unzip it
3. Get the images and resize them
4. Insert the new JPEGs to the new table.
5. Delete the zip file and uznipped folder which contains the images.

This task takes about three minutes for 1000 zip files (locally), so for 4 million zips it will take about 8.3 days (if there are no timeout problems etc). 
Doing it this way does not require a lot of storage since each zip is deleted after it's processed. The memory and processing consumption are fine as well.

What I'm looking for is a way to optimize my function. I am using asynchronous functions but the way they are constructed they don's save time, but only resources. Any ideas how to make the whole process faster?

This is how I'm calling my function

```
Await Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile()
```

My function:

```
' Application retrieving a large BLOB from Oracle using the new asynchronous capability
    Public Shared Async Function CopyBinaryValueToFile() As Task
        '{Time count
        Dim start_time As DateTime
        Dim stop_time As DateTime
        Dim elapsed_time As TimeSpan
        start_time = Now
        '}

        Dim sCurrentZip As String
        Dim sRecordID As String
        Dim sTempFolder As String = "TEMP"
        Dim oExtractedFiles As New ExtractedFiles

        'Create temporary folder for the zip files
        If Not Directory.Exists("TEMP") Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory("TEMP")
        End If

    Using connection As New OracleConnection(SettingsConnection.oracleCon)
        Await connection.OpenAsync()
        Using command As New OracleCommand("SELECT ch.RECORDID, ch.IMAGES FROM CHEQUES ch WHERE ch.RECORDID NOT IN (SELECT res.RECORDID FROM CHEQUES_RESIZED res)", connection)

            ' The reader needs to be executed with the SequentialAccess behavior to enable network streaming
            ' Otherwise ReadAsync will buffer the entire BLOB into memory which can cause scalability issues or even OutOfMemoryExceptions
            Using reader As OracleDataReader = Await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
                While Await reader.ReadAsync()
                    If reader.HasRows Then
                        If Not (Await reader.IsDBNullAsync(1)) Then
                            sRecordID = CStr(reader("RecordID"))
                            sCurrentZip = Path.Combine(sTempFolder, sRecordID & ".zip")  'specify filename which is the TEMP\recordid + .zip
                            Using file As New FileStream(sCurrentZip, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                                Using data As Stream = reader.GetStream(1)
                                    ' Asynchronously copy the stream from the server to the file we just created
                                    Await data.CopyToAsync(file)
                                    ' Unzip the file and store data related to the unzip to the object of ExtractedFiles
                                    oExtractedFiles = Await UnzipFile(sTempFolder, sCurrentZip, sRecordID)
                                End Using
                            End Using

                            If oExtractedFiles.IsSuccessful Then
                                'If they are successfully inserted to the resized table, then delete the leftover files
                                If Await StreamBLOBToServer(oExtractedFiles) Then
                                    Await DeleteExtractedData(oExtractedFiles)
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    '{Time count
    stop_time = Now
    elapsed_time = stop_time.Subtract(start_time)
    MessageBox.Show("elapsed_time = " & stop_time.Subtract(start_time).ToString & Environment.NewLine _
    & elapsed_time.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000000"))
    '}
End Function
```

Comment: You could run 4 or so parallel processes each assigned a subset of the data.  More processes can be used depending on how many processor cores you have and how io bound you are, would take some trial and error to come up with the optimal number.

Comment: _"Any ideas how to make the whole process faster?"_ Have you identified which component of it is the slowest bit?

Comment: Make your program take a parameter from 0 to 9. Only take records with their unique number ending with that digit. Run your software on 10 computers. If you save the zip files one the HD and unzip on the HD, that will slow down. Doing it all in memory might be much faster.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Anything related to the zipping/unzipping is slower than the rest, but I think the whole structure needs improvement. The task should be repeated by many processes in parallel which I'm do not know how to do it.

Comment: In that case, as @the_lotus says, it's probably disk access that's slow.  I would also look at attempting to do it all in memory - you might be able to more or less swap your `FileStream` for a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @JamesThorpe So the unzipping and image retrieval and references to the images will be done in memory as well?

Comment: Depending on what classes/libraries you're using for unzipping, and they support such things, yes